# How long should it take to upgrade to Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I know this isn't an easy question to answer with all of the dependencies.  But is it normal to take two months to upgrade?  And if we don't want it to hold up other releases while we are upgrading, what are the best ways to go about that?

I'm not a developer, by the way.  I'm on the product team.  But I'm curious understand what expectations I should have and how to fit this into our sprints.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure that this question is appropriate since we do not know anything about your enterprise level application and you have not provided details on your Rails 4 application to even give us an idea. Its a question that really one of your own developers should be answering. Sorry, but my comment is based on these rules: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I hear you and I know.  I'm trying to get an outside opinion outside of what my developers tell me.  And I'm not looking to hold anyone to the answer.  Just a ballpark.  Let's assume it is a complex application.  We are a SaaS business.

Comment: @Jason the best way is to run `rails app:update` on your dev machine 
 -> https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#the-update-task and see what it spits out. If the gems are already Rails 5 ready, then it should be a couple of hours work to tweak everything, since `app:update` will change the inheritance in controllers, etc. If you have some custom business logic, then it depends on how good of developer you are, but let's assume from couple of hours, to a couple of days at max.